# Possible to filter duplicate values during dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates, dictionary-comprehension

I'm creating a dictionary of random coordinates with indexes as their keys, and the coordinates must be unique.

I know I can go back through and filter the dictionary keys for duplicates after it is created, but **is it possible to ensure no duplicates in the process of creating the dictionary via comprehension**?

In pseudo code I would like to do something like:

```
 d = {k: (randint,randint) for k in range if (randint,randint) not in d}
```

But this references dictionary d before assignment.

To be clear, I'm creating a dictionary via comprehension, not modifying an existing dictionary.

Comment: there is no way to reference the dictionary being created by the dictionary comprehension. Just use a for-loop.

Comment: It might be possible but it will be ugly.  I second the recommendation to just use a for-loop.

Comment: Off-topic: You know that [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) is a function, and needs to be called to generate a value,. don't you?

Comment: Why don't generate unique coordinates from the get go?

Comment: yes, I know how to call randint, I was just trying to get the point across with pseudocode. I don't know how to generate coordinates that are random and guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As stated in comments, you should use a loop.

If you want to use some tricks, you have the old technique:

```
>>> from random import randint, seed
>>> seen = set()
>>> {k: (x, y) for k, x, y in ((k, randint(0,5),randint(0,5)) for k in range(50)) if (x, y) not in seen and not seen.add((x, y))}
{0: (3, 4), 1: (3, 3), 2: (4, 4), 3: (1, 1), 4: (4, 3), 5: (5, 4), 6: (1, 0), 7: (3, 2), 9: (4, 5), 10: (5, 0), 12: (3, 5), 14: (5, 1), 15: (4, 0), 17: (0, 0), 22: (1, 4), 23: (1, 5), 24: (2, 3), 25: (0, 5), 26: (0, 3), 27: (5, 2), 30: (2, 2), 32: (2, 0), 33: (0, 4), 35: (0, 2), 36: (3, 0), 38: (0, 1), 41: (5, 3)}
```

The generator `((k, randint(0,5),randint(0,5)) for k in range(50))` generates 50 coordinates with an index. The tuples `k, x, ,y` are tested: `if (x, y) not in seen`, we evaluate the second part of the `and`: `seen.add((x, y)` returns `None`, thus `not seen.add((x, y)` is always `True`, but performs a side effect (add the element to `seen`).

The drawback is that the size of the dict depends on the number of duplicates. To choose the number of elements, you'll have to: 1. create an infiinte generator; 2. take the N first unique elements.

You can create an infinite generator with the `iter` function and a fake sentinel (`(-1, -1)` will never be yielded):

```
>>> it = iter(lambda: (randint(0,5),randint(0,5)), (-1, -1))
```

Now with the `itertools` standard module, you can take the 10 first elements without duplicates:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> seen = set()
>>> dict(enumerate(itertools.islice(((x,y) for x, y in it if (x, y) not in seen and not seen.add((x, y))), 10)))
{0: (5, 0), 1: (0, 0), 2: (3, 3), 3: (1, 5), 4: (4, 1), 5: (3, 4), 6: (1, 3), 7: (5, 3), 8: (0, 3), 9: (3, 1)}
```

But you should use a loop...

Comment: [Downvoting should be reserved for extreme cases](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I want to accept this answer, is there a problem with the code proposed?

Comment: @M-Wi This code answers your question, but **I wouldn't use this code myself**. As written, you should use a loop and I would use a loop if I were you. So, why this answer? I think it's still useful to know some tricks, even if you don't use them, but some people seem to disagree.